# Which jurisdictions have made it illegal for people to travel to other jurisdictions for abortion?

Tags: abortion

It is well-known that some people who wish to obtain an abortion that is prohibited in the jurisdiction where they live will travel to another jurisdiction where said abortion would be legal. Last year, the US state of Georgia [tried to criminalize such travel for abortion](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2019/05/hb481-georgia-abortion-ban-criminal-brian-kemp-horrific.html).

1. In which jurisdictions is this *currently illegal*? (Assume that the person is an adult and they are travelling of their own free will.)
2. In which jurisdictions was it illegal at some point in the past? When were such laws repealed?

Comment: Are you asking about the USA or the world?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-M.Schröder world. There's nothing in the question to suggest US only.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably illegal in all of the jurisdictions in the US where a fetus is legally declared to be a person and where the murder statutes are written to not explicitly exclude abortion: that is, in **no** jurisdictions.

No law existing or proposed for Georgia specifically addresses "travel for the purpose of getting an abortion". The underlying theory behind the claim (advocated by some Georgia attorneys) is that a person may be open to a
conspiracy charge for taking a woman to another state to get an abortion, which would be a crime if committed in Georgia. If a conspiracy exists in Georgia to do something illegal (in Georgia), that is a violation of OCGA [16-4-8](https://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2018/title-16/chapter-4/section-16-4-8/) ("when he together with one or more persons conspires to commit any crime and any one or more of such persons does any overt act to effect the object of the conspiracy"). The substantially same law exists in [Washington](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=9A.28.040), and most if not all other states. The theory is apparently that "conspire to commit a crime" means something like "conspire to perform an act which would be a crime if performed in in this jurisdiction", e.g. "purchase marijuana, or take a job at certain payday loan companies". No state has successfully claimed [extraterritorial jurisdiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterritorial_jurisdiction#United_States), where a Georgia resident can be prosecuted in Georgia for a legal act carried out in another state, so this theory is a bit of a stretch.